# Terminate sndPlaySound32 when userform is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project with a main userform. Some child userform plays **a quite long wave file** when it opens. However, if the user closes the child form, the sound keeps playing. I could not find a way to terminate the sound event without killing all project userforms with it. I want to close the child form, from where the sound is triggered, and hear no sound, but continue to work on other forms. How to accomplish that? Below is my code so far.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sndPlaySound32 "F:\Program\Music\rainbow.wav", 1
End sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim FCR As Object
    Set FCR = FrmCredentials

    Unload FCR
    Set FCR = Nothing

    Load FrmIndex
    FrmIndex.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: Disabling `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` without enabling again might not be a good idea.

Comment: I will keep that in mind ! There are times, after running complex macros, some buttons, pictures, shapes placed at my worksheet project's appear to varnish. Yet, they can be seen when the spot they occupy is clicked. In those cases, minimizing the worksheet window or resizing do not make them visible again. I can only manage to retrieve them by closing and reopening Excel. At first glance, it seems to be a memory issue, but I have lots of free memory though. Do you think that this several `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` can be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop playing with

```
sndPlaySound32 vbNullString, &H1
```

or

```
sndPlaySound32 "NULL", &H1
```

---

Here is a full example:

```
Option Explicit

#if VBA7 then 'make it 64bit office compatible
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#else
    Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#end if

'  flag values for uFlags parameter
Const SND_SYNC = &H0            '  play synchronously (default)
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1           '  play asynchronously

Const SND_NODEFAULT = &H2       '  silence not default, if sound not found

Const SND_MEMORY = &H4          '  lpszSoundName points to a memory file
Const SND_ALIAS = &H10000       '  name is a WIN.INI [sounds] entry
Const SND_FILENAME = &H20000    '  name is a file name
Const SND_RESOURCE = &H40004    '  name is a resource name or atom
Const SND_ALIAS_ID = &H110000   '  name is a WIN.INI [sounds] entry identifier

Const SND_ALIAS_START = 0       '  must be > 4096 to keep strings in same section of resource file

Const SND_LOOP = &H8            '  loop the sound until next sndPlaySound
Const SND_NOSTOP = &H10         '  don't stop any currently playing sound
Const SND_VALID = &H1F          '  valid flags          / ;Internal /

Const SND_NOWAIT = &H2000       '  don't wait if the driver is busy

Const SND_VALIDFLAGS = &H17201F '  Set of valid flag bits.  Anything outside
                                '  this range will raise an error
Const SND_RESERVED = &HFF000000 '  In particular these flags are reserved

Const SND_TYPE_MASK = &H170007


Private Sub play()
    sndPlaySound32 "C:\Temp\spring.wav", SND_ASYNC
End Sub

Private Sub halt()
    sndPlaySound32 vbNullString, SND_ASYNC
End Sub
```

Comment: @PeH Thank you. It is now working. I also included a "loop". This I pasted into the close mode **UserForm_QueryClose**: `sndPlaySound32 vbNullString, SND_ASYNC + SND_LOOP` and, this, on to the activate mode **UserForm_Activate**: `sndPlaySound32 "F:\00_Program\Music\rainbow.wav", SND_ASYNC + SND_LOOP`

Comment: I think if you add more than one option, the options `SND_ASYNC + SND_LOOP` should be added with an `Or` like `(SND_ASYNC Or SND_LOOP)`.